# Integration by parts vs expanding giving different answers.

Tags: probability, integration

You are given the probability density function of a random variable X.

$$f_X(x) = 2x$$     $$0<x<1$$

Find the difference between the third central moment and the second central moment of this random variable.

My Solutions:

$E[X] = \int_0^{1} 2x^2 dx = \frac{2}{3}$

$(1)$ $E[ \left(X-\frac{2}{3} \right)^2] = 2 \int_0^{1} x\left(x-\frac{2}{3}\right)^2 dx$

$(2)$ $E[\left(X-\frac{2}{3}\right)^3] = 2 \int_0^{1} x\left(x-\frac{2}{3}\right)^3 dx$

When I use u-subsitution on $(1)$ & $(2)$ I get $\frac{1}{18}$ & $\frac{-1}{135}$ respectivley

If I expand the parenthesis instead I somehow end up with $\frac{1}{18}$ & $\frac{-29}{40}$ instead.

Why in the heck am I getting two different answers for the same integral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without looking at your work, it is impossible to know where exactly your mistake is but I get the same thing both times:

Using $u = x-2/3$ we see \begin{align*} \int^1_0 x\left(x-\tfrac 23 \right)^3 dx &= \int^{1/3}_{-2/3} \left(u+\tfrac 23 \right)u^3 du \\
&= \left[\frac{u^5}{5} + \frac{u^4}{6} \right]^{u=1/3}_{u=-2/3} \\
&= \frac{1}{5\cdot 243} + \frac 1 {2\cdot 243} + \frac{32}{5\cdot 243} - \frac {16} {2\cdot 243} \\
&=\frac{1}{243}\left( \frac{33}{5} - \frac {15} 2 \right) = -\frac {1}{243}\cdot \frac {9}{10} = -\frac1{270}. 
\end{align*}

Alternatively, we have \begin{align*} \int^1_0 x\left(x-\tfrac 2 3\right)^3 dx &= \int_0^1 x\left(x^3 -3x^2\left( \tfrac 2 3 \right) + 3x\left( \tfrac 2 3 \right)^2 - \left( \tfrac 2 3 \right)^3\right) dx\\
&=\int^1_0 x^4 - 2x^3+ \tfrac 4 3 x^2- \tfrac 8{27}x \, dx\\
&=\frac 1 5 - \frac 2 4 + \frac 4 9 - \frac 8 {54}\\
&= \frac{54 - 135 + 120 - 40}{270} = -\frac 1 {270}
\end{align*} [Notice, I left off the leading factor of $2$ so this agrees with your first evaluation of the integral.]